# FreeBSD display resolution under Veertu

Tags: xorg, freebsd, virtual-machine, graphics, apple

I'm trying to set up FreeBSD 10.3 under [Veertu](https://veertu.com/).

When starting X, the largest resolution I can get is 1280x720 (well, I can select 1280x768, but then I have to scroll). My actual screen is much bigger than that.

After `startx`, xrandr output is this:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gammma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1280 x 720, maximum 1280 x 768
default connected 1280x720+0+0 0mm x 0mm
  1280x720       0.00*
  1024x768      61.00
  800x600       61.00
  640x480       60.00
  1280x768       0.00
```

And `xvidtune -show`:

```
"1280x720"      0.00   1280    0    0    0    720    0    0    0
```

I tried playing around with xrandr and modelines but didn't find anything that works. it looks like, by the time xrandr can actually connect, the display has already been set to 1280x720 and will not change.

EDIT: note also that I can successfully change the console resolution with the method described [here](https://www.dan.me.uk/blog/2012/05/06/text-console-resolution-and-geometry-settings-in-freebsd-9-x/), so it looks like the vesa driver should be able to handle it.

The Veertu people seem to suggest this is a *nix thing that can be changed before X starts, but I don't know how you'd get about that. Any suggestions?